# Trying to change environment variable within RSpec model spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, model, environment-variables

I've got one User model which has different validations based on an environmental variable ENV['APP_FOR']. This can either be "app-1" or "app-2". app-1 validates for username while app-2 validates for email address. Here is my User model spec for app-1:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  include Shared::Categories

  before do
    ENV['APP_FOR']='app-1'
  end

  context "given a valid User" do
    before { allow_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:older_than_18?).and_return(true) }

    it {should validate_presence_of :username}
  end
end
```

And this is the User model spec for app-2

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, type: :model do

  include Shared::Categories

  before do
    ENV['APP_FOR']='app-2'
  end

  context "given a valid User" do
    before { allow_any_instance_of(User).to receive(:older_than_18?).and_return(true) }

    it {should validate_presence_of :email}
  end
end
```

My problem is that the environment variable isn't being set as I would expect it to be in the before block. Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT 1

Here is my validation implementation. I used a concern which I extend the user model with:

```
module TopDogCore::Concerns::UserValidations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do

    if ENV['APP_FOR'] == 'app-1'
      validates :username,
                presence: true,
                uniqueness: true        

    elsif ENV['APP_FOR'] == 'app-2'
      validates :email, 
                presence: true,
                uniqueness: true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: could you post your validation implementation?

Comment: @IgorBelo check out the new edit above, I've included it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
module TopDogCore::Concerns::UserValidations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do

    validates :username,
      presence: true,
      uniqueness: true, if: -> { ENV['APP_FOR'] == 'app-1' }

    validates :email,
      presence: true,
      uniqueness: true, if: -> { ENV['APP_FOR'] == 'app-2' }
  end
end
```

Comment: Correction, it worked!! Thanks! wrapping my validations with lambda's works!

Answer (score 2):

RSpec loads the subject class before running code in the examples. When you do this:

```
before do
  ENV['APP_FOR'] = # ...
end
```

it is too late. The class definition has already been executed. You can see this for yourself by simply printing the value of `ENV['APP_FOR']` from within the class definition (in your case, the included concern). It is `nil`, since the environment variable was not set when the class source file was loaded.

Deferring evaluation by using a lambda ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35037652/17410)) ought to work. You might try using your own test instead of the one provided by `shoulda_matchers`, eg.:

```
expect(subject.valid?).to be false
expect(subject.errors[:username].blank?).to be false
```

Answer (score 0):

Stub your constant like this

```
before do
  stub_const("APP_FOR", 'app-2')
end
```

Checkout the [Stubbing Constants](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants/stub-defined-constant) docs